# How does this work? Optional first argument used in Express (err, req, res, next) or (req, res, next)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, node.js-connect

With Express / Connect I can set up an middleware function in either of the formats:

```
function(req, res, next) // first argument will be a request
```

Or

```
function(err, req, res, next) // first argument will be an error
```

Stepping back from Express, Connect, to basic JavaScript: I don't understand is how this is possible to have an **optional first argument**?

How can express know that my function will accept an `err` object first? I thought to make this possible the structure would have to be like the following:

```
function(req, res, next, err)
```

Am I missing something basic here? Is it possible to query how many arguments a function is expecting?

The middleware function is passed to express, so the `arguments` variable is not valid. although `length` is correct... I think I have figured it out, would be good to have confirmation to whether this is the case. Example below:

```
var fn;

fn = function (one, two) {};
console.log(fn.length); // 2

fn = function (one, two, three) {};
console.log(fn.length); // 3
```

Comment: I was always wondering if it would be possible or not, then convinced myself that its not!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I think I have figured it out, would be good to have confirmation to whether this is the case
>
> ```
> var fn;
>
> fn = function (one, two) {};
> console.log(fn.length); // 2
>
> fn = function (one, two, three) {};
> console.log(fn.length); // 3
> ```

Yes, that's correct. The `length` property of a `Function` instance is the number of *formal parameters* (declared arguments) it has. This is hidden away in [Section 13.2](http://es5.github.com/#x13.2) of the spec, steps 14 and 15.

So it's quite easy for the code calling the function to check `fn.length` and pass it the optional first argument, or not, depending on that. This does mean, of course, that it's entirely possible to write a function that *would* handle the four-argument version, but fools the framework by using `arguments` rather than formal parameters. So you wouldn't do that. :-)

*(Apologies for misreading your question the first time.)*

Comment: *p.s. do you know the name of this technique?*

Comment: @Ross: Sorry, I missed that comment. I don't know that it has a specific name. You're tested the *[arity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arity)* of the function.

Answer (score 2):

The first function has 3 arguments, the second one has 4 arguments, so Express/Connect looks at the number of arguments.

It's not possible to switch between arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Express spends quite a long time looking at the [arity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arity) of the function; i.e. how many arguments that are in there:

```
function foo(err, req, res, next) {
    if (arguments.length === 3) { // err isn't there
        next = res;
        res = req;
        req = err;
    }
    ...
}
```

So. Detect how many arguments there are, and shuffle variables accordingly. I've even seen some Node.js-modules that does the automatically for you.

And while I haven't checked up recently, there were some cases where messing with the `arguments`-builtin would disable all optimizations in V8.